# Unable to resolve dependency issue @angularx-social-login

Tags: angular

I'm using the Angular v 12 and `@abacritt/angularx-social-login` for social login but its not working and getting dependency issue.

Also I couldn't resolve the issue for adding google button `asl-google-signin-button` which is not found.

I don't want to upgrade the Angular version, and when I tried to use `npm i angularx-social-login`, it should work.

How can I install a `@abacritt/angularx-social-login` compatible with Angular v12?

Answer (score 0):

According to the package [repository](https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login) i found the compatibility Matrix bellow :

[image]

Thus try bellow one:

```
npm i angularx-social-login@4.1.0
```